# Rails includes with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

Let's say I've got this relation:

```
Users has_many Orders, Visits
```

For each user, I want to compose an object like so:

```
{Name: user.name, Orders: user.orders, Visits: user.visits}
```

And I want to restrict visits to those occurring in the past year, and orders to those occurring in the past month. Right now I'm trying to use this query:

```
Users.includes(:Visits, :Orders).where('Visit.occurred_on > ?', 1.year.ago)
                                .where('Order.date > ?', 1.month.ago)
                                .references(:Visits, :Orders)
```

The problem is, this returns only those users where both where conditions are met because the conditions are applied after the outer joins. Is there a way to only include the records I'm looking for?

Comment: There're a few problems with the naming conventions used that might be throwing you off. The model names should be singular (i.e. `User`) and the hash keys lowercase. The `includes` should then by lowercase, pluralised symbols. Finally, your `where` clauses should include the database table name in the SQL - this is conventionally lowercase, pluralised. I'm not sure if this will solve the problem here - but maybe worth looking at?

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your query like this:

```
Users.includes(:Visits, :Orders).where('Visit.occurred_on > ? AND Order.date > ?', 1.year.ago, 1.month.ago)
```

Let me know this is worked for you or not.

> Note: Query didn't tested

Comment: That is a better way of writing the query. Unfortunately, it doesn't change the result. It still performs the includes joins and THEN applies the where conditions.